# Как элемент на странице в браузере найти в коде проекта wordpress для правки?

Tags: wordpress

У меня вопрос к знатокам wordpress. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в проекте найти файл, в котором формируется определенная страница?

Подробнее:
Есть проект, в котором куча плагинов написанных под одну тему (а  вних еще больше файлов). Нужно сделать правки на странице создания события. Вот адресс страницы создания события у меня на локалке:

```
http://drink.loc/add-listing/?listing_type=gd_event
```

Адресс страницы редактирования события:

```
http://drink.loc/edit-event/?event_id=705&listing_type=gd_event
```

место, где редактируется я нашел - это файл темы functions.php, который на 4300 строк...туда впихнули верстку для блока редактирования события.
Инспетором через мазилу id-ки искал, но там классы, id и всё формируется так, что при помощи инспектора браузера название нужное не найдешь. Буду рад любым подсказкам, мыслям и Вашему глубочайшему опыту! Заранее спасибо!
П.С.: работаю с  PHPStorm, но поиск помог найти только место, где редактируется файл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите на готовую страницу в браузере, ищите более или менее уникальные стили, идентификаторы, теги html (например, `<article`).

Потом Ctrl+Shift+F в phpStorm - поиск в проекте (или в папке плагина, или темы). Отлично работает, использую такую методику постоянно.

Comment: Да, отличная практика, мне всегда тоже помогала. Но, к сожалению, проект сильно замудрен, индификаторы и классы формируются так же и из разных частей php кода, но не беда, понаходил я нужные поля, все это в громадном файле functions.php (4300 строк), но это ВСЁ относится к редактированию события (там я правки уже сделал), а не к созданию события (где еще нужно сделать правки)...

Comment: Подумаешь, 4300 строк )) Я прямо сейчас работаю с темой, у которой в function.php 5300 строк, а всего в ней 105 тыс строк, и ничего ))

Comment: снимаю шляпу)))) и Вы ВСЁ находили благодаря поиску PHPStorm?Я же говорю, что я так сделал, нашел нужные мне строки для части редактирования. Теперь нужно еще и для созданию события найти. Но все id, классы и тд. либо относятся к редактированию, где я сделал правки, либо не находятся, потому, что формируются при помощи php-кода. Проверил все, что можноиз блока где нужно сделать правки. Что бы Вы сделали бы на моем месте?

Comment: Нашел бы ))) Трудно сказать, через какие именно фрагменты, классы css (через них проще всего), но нашел бы. Ну, в отладчике бы потыкал код, в крайнем случае.

Comment: От размеров почти ничего не зависит. Исходный код woocommerce - 325 тыс строк, ядро WordPress - 500 тыс строк. И все равно нахожу нужные куски кода, чтобы понять, как это хозяйство работает.

Comment: Позвонил сотруднику SAP, имеющему доступ к исходном коду. Он занимает 2ГБ текста, примерно 50 миллионов строк. Так что наши WordPress проектики - просто детские игрушки))

Comment: закрою вопрос, т.к., исходя из него, созрел другой, более конкретный. А на этот вопрос Вы дали верный ответ, хоть я так и делал, но не решил свою проблему...П.С.: интересно ЧТО же можно написать на движке WP на 50 миллионов строк...0_0 Уже проще было бы написать движок под свои нужны помоему))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68070/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).