# Адаптация сайта на wordpress под мобильные устройства

Tags: wordpress, адаптивность

У меня есть доступ к хостингу сайта работающего на *wordpress*.

Необходимо отредактировать несколько баннеров для адаптации под мобильные телефоны.

В просмотре кода элемента в браузере видно, где элемент находится в *html*, но на сервере php-файлы вижу. Сам *html* где-то есть? Не работал раньше с *wordpress*, но в курсе, что в нём вёрстка распределяется по файлам php.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Вам не понятно как устроено распределение по шаблонам в Wordpress или надо найти конкретный элемент?
Так как WP использует темы то реализация отображения может быть разная: плагины, шаблоны, виджеты, скрипты etc. 
С большой долей вероятности вы можете найти управление баннерами в админ панели

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ на похожий вопрос. Там сказано, как искать куски кода php, отвечающего за создание html https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738972/220220

Comment: Самого html в полном виде вы не найдете ни в файлах сайта, ни в базе. Суть WordPress и подобных систем управления контента в том, что html код страницы строится динамически, с помощью php.