# Правка html сайта на wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

У сайта на wordpress есть элемент, у которого фон задан через атрибут style в html, вижу это через просмотр кода элемента в браузере, можно ли как-то найти этот фрагмент кода на хостинге сайта, и отредактировать его?

Comment: Можете скачать сайт и воспользоваться например notepad++, или специальными программами для поиска текста в файлах.

Comment: Код может добавляться через JS,  найти страницу в теме, узнав как называется страница, например content.php или single.php в зависимости от того где отображен элемент.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738972/220220

Answer (score 0):

В файле css задайте стиль с пометкой !important, это перебивает инлайн стили

```
.a{
   margin:10px!important;
}
```

Comment: Ответ не в тему. Вопрос о том, как **изменить** фрагмент кода html, редактируя php. И, кроме того, далеко не всегда с помощью important можно перебить inline стили. Обычно приходится делать более квалифицированное правило, например, от body (body .a), чтобы перекрыть inline стили.