# Как удалить/изменить footer в теме Metro Magazine в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: Скриншот 1]

[image: скриншот 2]

Не могу разобраться, какую строку нужно удалить для изменения футора. Конкретно запись копирайта автора темы. Возможно ли это вообще в данной теме?

Comment: А здесь не видно что `html` кусок футера не тут

Comment: Я пробовал искать по остальным файлам темы, но ничего не нашел. Понимаю, что это необходимо детально рассматривать знающему человеку (я новичок просто), но может быть подскажете, стоит ли тогда менять тему, раз авторы "запрятали" файл футера? Или же есть какой-то способ поиска нужного файла или предполагаемое расположение?

Comment: Стоит если вам это нужно

Comment: Что именно "изменить"? Допиши в вопросе.

Comment: Автор, у меня та же проблема. Если ты решил её, то ответь пожалуйста - как. Из комментов ничего не понял. Можно на почту ответить. Если кто ответит - боольшое спасибо.
m.rus.alb@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы что-то изменить в футере нужно

1. Создать дочернюю тему.  И сделать это лучше с пом плагина  [child theme configurator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/) настроив описания и главное - указав копирование настроек родителя.
2. В дочке создать [файл функций](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.A4.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BB_.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D1.84.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.BA.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B0) (functions.php). Не скопировать его из родителя, а создать!
3. В этот файл функций из [/inc/template-functions.php](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/metro-magazine/1.1.4/inc/template-functions.php) скопировать нужную функцию `metro_magazine_footer_xxx` и изменить её по своему усмотрению.

*Более детально могу рассказать после того, как будет уточнён вопрос.*

*Ида. Не использовать редактор ВП, если нет твёрдого желания поломать сайт. Только правильные блокноты с подсветкой синтаксиса и в кодировке UTF-8 с загрузкой файлов по ФТП.*

Comment: И этот ответ поддержу) все правильно.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет. Мне конкретно необходимо было удалить строку из футера с копирайтингом автора темы. К сожалению, туториалы не помогли, люди посоветовали спросить здесь. Теперь понимаю, что необходимо создавать дочернюю тему. Но  это все порождает много новых вопросов, например, заполнение файла functions.php, но думаю, тут стоит почитать кодекс ВП. В общем, если еще что-то посоветуете, буду только рад, если нет, то огромное спасибо за уделенное мне время

Comment: @КонстантинМорзе файл просто создать файл и скопировать в него функцию `metro_magazine_footer_credit` (1099-1119 строки) изменив код как хочется. Знания htnl и не много php обязательны.

Answer (score 1):

[do_action()](https://misha.blog/wordpress/do_action.html) говорит вам о том, что в этом месте шаблона должна выполняется определённая функция, описанная в 99% случаев в файле **`functions.php`**. Ищите в нём функции с названиями **`metro_magazine_footer`** и **`metro_magazine_page_end`**. Смотрите, что возвращают эти функции. Если это не поможет вам решить задачу, то вы хотя бы сможете немного конкретизировать вопрос.

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ. Небольшое дополнение на тему, как найти любой код для правки в WordPress: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738972/220220

Answer (score 0):

Зачем делать дочерку? Код если логично подумать находиться в файле с названием functions. В этой теме их 2. Второй називаеться tamplete-functions.php. Он находиться в папке inc. А вот и то что мы ищем [image: введите сюда описание изображения]