# Кастом рейтинга Woocommrce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте.

На сайте с использованием Woocomerce есть возможность добавления отзывов с рейтингом(выглядит как на картинке). Как видоизменить звездочки? Я хочу чтобы их было всего пять. В каком файле это обычно выводится?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это все зависит от темы. Какая у вас тема?

Comment: Как найти код для правки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738972/220220

Comment: Emmet Lite тема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройки вашей темы (Внешний вид->Настроить) добавьте такой css:

```
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-2,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-3,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-4,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-5 {
    border: none;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}

.woocommerce p.stars a.star-1:after,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-2:after,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-3:after,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-4:after,
.woocommerce p.stars a.star-5:after {
  content: "\f005";
}

.woocommerce p.stars a:hover~a::after {
    color: #d9e4ef;
}

.woocommerce p.stars:hover a::after {
    color: #27b399;
}
```

Comment: Сработало. А как при клике на 5ю(например) звезду подсвечивать остальные?

Comment: Добавил два правила в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Все как часы)