# Не звездный рейтинг для WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Сейчас мой сайт использует звездный рейтинг такого вида (в товарах `Woocommerce`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это очень не красиво, как звездный рейтинг(то что они разделены), но проблема не в этом. Нужно сделать рейтинг через лайк\дислайк по этому примеру(палец вверх\вниз)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как подобное сделать не приложу ума, потому что не знаю есть ли у `WP` функции рейтинга помимо `wp_star_rating()`. 
В общем прошу направления(а может и решения) куда двигаться.

`WordPress 4.9.2 / Woocommerce 3.2.6 / Emmet Lite theme 1.7.0`

Comment: "Сейчас мой сайт использует звездный рейтинг такого вида... Это очень не красиво, как звездный рейтинг(то что они разделены)"  -
 Я не понял, а зачем я вам отвечал на вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771159/220220

Comment: Меняю концепцию. Ваше правило работало отлично, но нужно сделать через "пальцы".

Answer (score 0):

Без костылей не обойтись. Я бы сперва сделал вывод количества лайков:

```
<?php
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
?>
```

Затем написал бы функции с выполнением через AJAX по принципу получения текущего рейтинга и изменения в сторону лайка/дизлайка:

```
<?php
$rating = $rating_count - 1; // Дизлайк
$rating = $rating_count + 1; // Лайк

update_post_meta($product_id, '_wc_rating_count', $rating);
//update_post_meta($product_id, '_wc_review_count', $rating);
?>
```

Я много нюансов опустил, но принцип должен быть понятен.

Comment: Ну а почему костыли. Нормальный код, так и должно выглядеть решение.

Comment: Только я не уверен, что _wc_review_count то, что нужно, а не общее количество отзывов о продукте. Давно смотрел этот код, но мне кажется, там иначе сделано.

Comment: Верно, там скорее всего _wc_rating_count, но опять же надо тестить.