# Как поменять местами в каталоге?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Как поменять местами в каталоге символ и цену, чтобы символ был после цены? Это не в карточке товара, а в общем каталоге.

Код:

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $sale ? '<span class="old-price">' . $reg_price . $currency . '</span> ' $price . $currency : $price . $currency;?>/1000шт</span>
```

Comment: Какой плагин электронного магазина? Их с десяток разных.

Comment: Woocommerce плагин

Answer (score 0):

Используйте настройку WooCommerce->Настройки->Настройки валюты->Позиция обозначения валюты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем коде синтаксис - не хватает точки после `'</span> '`

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $sale ? '<span class="old-price">' . $reg_price . $currency . '</span> ' . $price . $currency : $price . $currency;?>/1000шт</span>
```

Comment: Это я понимаю, но у меня меняется только в карточке товара, а не меняется в каталоге

Comment: Что-то ломает WooCommerce - тема или плагин. Эта опция работает везде по умолчанию. Только что проверил на тестовом сайте.

Comment: ломает тема, я бы просто хотел узнать, где возможно это увидеть?

Comment: В теме есть папка woocommerce, в ней archive-product.php. Скорее всего, именно этот шаблон сделан неправильно. Он использует много других, вложенных. Сказать точно, не видя сайта, - невозможно. Посмотрите этот ответ на предмет общих рекомендаций, как найти код в WP https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738972/220220

Comment: Вот сайт: https://beleksprint.by/shop/

Comment: Код выше написал

Comment: И что этот код - он пустой, там идет вызов content-product.php и т.д. Вникните в ответ, который я дал по ссылке, найдите код, который выводит `<span class="price">бел.рублей25</span>` и разбирайтесь с ним.

Comment: В этом проблема: <span class="price"><?php echo $sale ? '<span class="old-price">' . $currency . $reg_price . '</span> ' . $currency . $price : $currency . $price;?></span> меняю местами, у меня страница не отображает

Comment: Приведите в вопросе рабочий код и как вы его пытаетесь изменить. Там есть кнопка "править"

Comment: Синтаксис - добавил в ответ. Пользуйтесь современными IDE, не будет таких проблем.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можете посоветовать IDE'шку, потому что VS Studio не помогает что-то

Comment: Я работаю с phpStorm. Ну а так-то их много: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/top-ide-and-code-editors-php-development/

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.